# Clustering Group of Products using K-means

Tags: pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby, cluster-analysis, k-means

Use case: cluster group of cloth products using column `look_id`

Sample of data :

[image]

The initial step was to change categorical data to numerical using `LabelEncoder`

[image]

Pseudo Code :

- Group LookIDs in dataFrame
- Data Preprocessing Change df to Numpy Array
- Cluster using K-means

I have started by transform GroupBy df to Numpy Array but the result was not convenient trailing zero

Sample

```
[[['Hackett', 'Shorts', 'Pink', 'Light', 'SS17'], ['Diesel', 'T-Shirt', 'Navy', 'Dark', 'AW17'], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], [['Hackett', 'Blazer', 'Green', 'Medium', 'AW16'], ['Reiss', 'Formal Shirts', 'Blue', 'Medium', 'AW17'], ['Van Gils', 'Lace up', 'Black', 'Dark', 'SS17']
```

DataFrame to Numpy Code Sample :

```
  g = m.groupby('look_id').cumcount()
  L = (m.set_index(['look_id',g])
       .unstack(fill_value=0)
       .stack().groupby(level=0)
       .apply(lambda x: x.values.tolist())
       .tolist())
```

How I can represent this correctly and do clustering

Comment: It does not answer your question, but it is really weird to use a `KNN` algorithm on categorical data, especialy if those categories have more than 2 possible values, are you doing that on purpose ?

Comment: I would like to find pattern and collection between groups. What are the other alternatives . Thanks for your reply